# Question erroneously declared to be a duplicate

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

[How can I create multipart tar file in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/198857/how-can-i-create-multipart-tar-file-in-linux)

This question is currently number one result in Google for ["how to create multipart rar in Linux"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q=how%20to%20create%20multipart%20rar%20in%20linux&oq=how%20to%20create%20multipart%20rar%20in%20linux&gs_l=hp.3..33i21.142.7018.0.7135.42.33.4.4.6.0.194.3903.8j24.32.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.RIFJ0ov4fWg).

[The question that they claim is a duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/189691/how-to-split-a-tar-file-into-smaller-parts-at-file-boundaries) is *NOT* a duplicate: It asks a much more technical question that is not relevant at all to the vast majority of people who are searching for my question.

Thank you for investigating this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems legit. I reopened the question. Thanks for letting us know :)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.